# Word remains in the background despite the "Active" function VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to make barcode label sheets for items. For this I use Excel with VBA and a "user form" to help the user in entering the number and information of bar codes. Once I have all my information for my barcodes, I transfer its information to a Word in which I format it to make printable labels.

My system works fine, although a bit long when there are a large number of labels to transfer, but once word and excel have been closed once when I want to restart the transfers, Word no longer comes to the fore , which makes me completely miss the transfer. I am using the tab key which is the main source of the problem.

I have tried performing the same actions as the tab key with other commands like "next" so that it is no longer a problem. However this does not work entirely because the tab key allows at the end of a page to continue the layouts on a new page which the "next" function does not do.

So my questions are: How can I force Word to come to the fore? Can we replace the tab key with another parameter that allows me to do the same thing?

I provide you below the code of my loop performing the transfer.

```
Dim appwd As Word.Application
Dim oDoc As Object
Dim Code As String, SKU As String, Name As String, Size As String
Dim DerLign As Byte
    With Sheets("Reference")
        DerLign = .Cells(.Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    On Error Resume Next
    Set appwd = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If Err Then
        Set appwd = New Word.Application
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    With appwd
        If .Documents.Count = 0 Then
            .Documents.Add
        End If
        Set oDoc = .MailingLabel.CreateNewDocument("3474")
        .Visible = True
        .Activate
        
    ' Colle les données dans Word
    For i = 8 To DerLign
        Code = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reference").Range("B" & i)
        SKU = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reference").Range("C" & i)
        Name = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reference").Range("D" & i)
        Size = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reference").Range("E" & i)
        appwd.Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 1
        appwd.Selection.TypeParagraph
        appwd.Selection.TypeText Text:=SKU
        appwd.Selection.TypeParagraph
        appwd.Selection.Font.Name = "Code EAN13"
        appwd.Selection.Font.Size = 40
        appwd.Selection.TypeText Text:=Code
        appwd.Selection.Font.Name = "Calibri"
        appwd.Selection.Font.Size = 11
        appwd.Selection.TypeParagraph
        appwd.Selection.TypeText Text:=Name + "     " + Size
        SendKeys "{TAB}", False
    Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Regards

Comment: Instead of `.Activate`, please try `AppActivate .ActiveWindow.Caption`...

Comment: Thank you so much @FaneDuru. It's work perfectly, I wasted so much time on this. Oooh thank you.